# Finding contiguous array

Tags: java, arrays, sub-array

I am trying to get an output of [4,6,6,7] with length 4 where arr[i] <= arr[i+1] where it is non-decreasing and it is contiguous. I know what i have to do but i dont know how to do it. my code prints out [3,4,6,6,7]. I am just having trouble on the contiguous part, any help? im not allowed to use extra arrays.

```
public static void ascentLength(int arr[], int size) {
    int length = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int count = 1;
      
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        index = i;
        if (arr[0] <= arr[i+1] && count >0) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+ " index:" + index); 
            length++;
            count++;
        }          
        if (arr[0] >= arr[i+1]) {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("length: " + length);
}
  
 
/* Driver program to test above function */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 5};
    int n = arr.length;
    ascentLength(arr, n);
}
```

Comment: Its kind of conflicting with your own requirement. 3,4,6,6,7 also matches your non-decreasing condition and when u say length 4...last 4 or first 4 ? and what happens when there are multiple sets of 4 elements ?

Comment: Well, your code works well. The largest contiguous part from your `array` is `{4, 6, 6, 7}`, so where exactly do you see the problem?

Comment: when you do the comparison, lets say starting the comparison at index 1 to index 2. its 3 ≤ 6 which is correct, however 6≤4 is not correct. but then 4≤6 is correct. but 3 and 4 are not adjacent to each other so it shouldnt be printing 3. im not sure if this makes sense im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My code prints out {3,4,6,6,7} when it needs to only print {4,6,6,7} @AP11

Comment: @some_cs_student Try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it would be easier, if you could work with `List`, but this works for arrays:

```
public static void ascentLength(int arr[], int size) {
    if(size == 1) System.out.println("length: 1");

    // variables keeping longest values
    int longestStartingIndex = 0;
    int longestLength = 1;

    // variables keeping current values        
    int currentStartingIndex = 0;
    int currentCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i-1] <= arr[i]) {
            currentCount++;
        } else {
            // check if current count is the longest
            if(currentCount > longestLength) {
                longestLength = currentCount;
                longestStartingIndex = currentStartingIndex;
            }
            currentStartingIndex = i;
            currentCount = 1;
        }
    }
    if(currentCount > longestLength) {
        longestLength = currentCount;
        longestStartingIndex = currentStartingIndex;
    }
}
```